# Convert an audio input to text with SAPI

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, sapi

i want to convert an audio input which is being given through the microphone into text. i prefer to do this with SAPI and C# any suggestions? or code samples?

Thanks !!

Comment: yes, but how to do it using that namespace? i searched on Google and get lot of links but i am confused about that grammar thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to view some previous threads, including [getting started with speech recognition and speech synthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881015/getting-started-with-speech-recognition-and-speech-synthesis/3882284)

From that thread:
There is a very good article that was published a few years ago at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx. It is probably the best introductory article I’ve found so far...

Comment: For a similar question, I posted some simple sample code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem/4217638#4217638