# What libraries (C or Python) can I use under Linux to write software that recognizes voice commands?

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I have a request for a software contract that calls for recognizing spoken commands from a very limited set, such as "up", "down", "close", "open" etc.

I don't seem to need full-blown speech recognition, i. e. I don't have to do wave-to-text transformation. Is there a specific term I could google?

I simply don't know enough about the subject to be able to code that stuff myself. If I want to tackl ethis at all, I would need a fairly mature library for this subproblem, preferrably open source.

The target platform would be some kind of industrial PC running Linux and I would use either C or Python for the application.

Comment: Actually, you *do* need a full-blown speech recognition system.  What you're probably thinking of is a dictation recognition system, which is much harder than a "command and control" recognition system (which only recognizes utterances within a fixed, but possibly complex, grammar).  CMU Sphinx, as far as I know, is a command and control recognizer, but I haven't used it for any real projects.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a suitable candidate: [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/).

Haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out pyspeech, but I think it is Windows only. See [Speech processing library in Python for speech to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873982/speech-processing-library-in-python-for-speech-to-text/4876444)