# Speech recognition library for known limited dictionary

Tags: java, .net, c++, speech-recognition

I'm looking for a good speech recognition library for a known limited dictionary.
For example a list of names in a phone book, or city addresses.

Comment: Hey I have the exact same problem, any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)

> An open source toolkit for speech recognition, which includes a recognizer library written in C; an adjustable, modifiable recognizer written in Java
>
> CMU Sphinx Toolkit is actively used in speech recognition research

Comment: As I know Sphinx require audio dictionary and im looking for some tools that works with text dictionaries. Currently I found that only MS speech recognition can do that.

Comment: Speech recognition tools on Linux and the FOSS community are rare and limited. The only well standing project I know is `Sphinx`. If you're interested you could extend it. It _may_ be easy.

Answer (score 1):

See [Text-to-speech (voice generation) and speech-to-text (voice recognition) APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348770/text-to-speech-voice-generation-and-speech-to-text-voice-recognition-apis)

> Windows folks - use the System.Speech
>   features of .Net or Microsoft.Speech
>   and install the free recognizers
>   Microsoft provides. Windows 7 includes
>   a full speech engine. Others are
>   downloadable for free. There is a C++
>   API to the same engines known as SAPI.
>   See at
>   [Exploring New Speech Recognition And Synthesis APIs In Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx)
>   or
>   [Microsoft Speech API (SAPI) 5.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
>   More background on Microsoft engines
>   for Windows
>   [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-rec)

Answer (score 0):

maybe google voice? search by the wavelet and parse the result for searched string

Comment: As I know Google has no public API for this service