# Does Anyone Uses Google Speech API in Production?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have found some articles (http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/) describing how to use the Google speech API.

However, is this reliable? Does anyone uses it in production?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Google's speech web services are only legitimately used by their Chrome browser or Android operating system. You can certainly build a production Chrome or Android app that relies on these services. Both Chrome and Android documentation describe how to add speech features to applications. (Good links include http://chrome.blogspot.com/2011/04/everybodys-talking-and-translating-with.html and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html)

However, notice the article you reference the author had to dig through the Chrome source code to reverse engineer the network speech APIs. Google has not published the direct network APIs for use by other clients (non-Chrome, non-Android). I don't believe Google intends for developers to build directly to their non-published network APIs. I would not rely on those APIs for a production application because Google could easily throttle or shut off access for unauthorized clients.

Comment: I agree with Michael Levy that you should not count on an unsupported Google API in production. A lot of developers used the Google Weather API which was also unsupported and they recently shut it down as you can see in this blog post http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2012/08/google-weather-api-is-dead.html.

Comment: Reading through the Chromium source code, they have moved to a model where Chromium uses Google APIs in a way which requires you to get your own API key (instructions [http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys here]). It would make sense then that the Speech API is then supported in some form or fashion.