# Using Google Api: Speech To Text on PC Version

Tags: mfc, speech-recognition

Google Chrome provide speech to text(STT) and So many smart phone apps provide STT. It has good recognition.

I want program in Visual Studio(MFC), But there's no methods to do STT. If I use Google Speech To Text Api, It's so easy to settle this problem.

If there's no public google api about STT, Tell me another way to this except with start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, Google has not documented their speech API and do not intend it to be used by general purpose clients. I believe their intent is for the speech API to support their Android and Chrome products. That said, there is more information at [Does Anyone Uses Google Speech API in Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879804/does-anyone-uses-google-speech-api-in-production) and [Is there an API for Google's speech recognition technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830203/is-there-an-api-for-googles-speech-recognition-technology).

Since you're programming for Windows, why don't you use the built in Windows speech engine. You can use the System.Speech features of .Net or Microsoft.Speech and install the free recognizers Microsoft provides. Windows 7 includes a full speech engine. Others are downloadable for free. There is a C++ API to the same engines known as SAPI. See at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx. or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=vs.85).aspx. More background on Microsoft engines for Windows
[What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-rec)

One last link that I hope is helpful, here is a simple example of speech recogntion in .NET - [SAPI and Windows 7 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem)

Comment: I attempt with Microsoft engine but its recognition rate has fall down. If you have other source or document, please share with me.

Comment: I've found the Microsoft speech recognition quality to be very good. Perhaps you can explain what problems you've had and post a question so people can help you get better results.

Comment: Where Can  I find high quality microsoft speech recognition sample?

Comment: In my answer to your question I put a link to a StackOverflow post that includes a good example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem.

Comment: The problem with Microsoft's speech api is that it doesn't work for most languages, working with only some of them while in Google's case it's the reverse. Same for their speech synthesis, really.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this: https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160 useful. Basically you need to send FLAC-encoded audio file to google servers in POST request. Be aware that it accept only audio files of 15 seconds of less (for simple voice command app it would be enough).

I'm looking into thing like this and MS Speech API isn't for me, even if is good, because it doesn't support most languages Google's API does (example being Polish, same for MS text-to-speech).