# Speech recognition library for OSX?

Tags: python, osx-lion, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

So I've been looking around the web for a Python Speech recognition, and I found pyspeech. But that is only for Windows. I would like a Speech Recognition Library that works with Mac aswel. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerCrompton It is not a Product. It is simply a library, and its free. It can't be poorer quality than nothing.

Comment: You do realize those libraries just interface with the voicerec APIs that the underlying OS provides? Any API that osx has is going to be fundamentally different from whatever windows has.

Comment: @Markb right, but theres no library that works with macs...

Comment: @PlazmotechBinary, a library *is* a product regardless of its price. From the link I provided: "Seek explanations, not suggestions."

Comment: Perhaps some older questions and answers can help you get started, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6348770/90236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://andrewbrobinson.com/2012/02/29/speech-recognition-using-sphinx-dont-try-this-at-home/ suggests that Pocket Sphinx includes Python bindings and is easy to use.

Another helpful resource may be the video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VA2Th121zQ

Also, from http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/

> Sphinx-4 has been built and tested on the Solaris TM Operating
>   Environment, Mac OS X, Linux and Win32 operating systems. Running,
>   building, and testing Sphinx-4 requires additional software. Before
>   you start, you will need the following software available on your
>   machine.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has open sourced their project DeepSpeech, a tensorflow implementation of Baidu's DeepSpeech architecture:

- https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2017/11/29/announcing-the-initial-release-of-mozillas-open-source-speech-recognition-model-and-voice-dataset/
- https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comparison table with a lot of libraries you may want to consider. (Written by Alberto Pettarin)

https://github.com/pettarin/forced-alignment-tools