# Speech to Text API or SDK for Mobile (Cross-Platform)

Tags: android, ios, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

What are the best currently supported speech or text API or SDK for mobile (multiple platforms: Android, iOS, etc)

There are a few posts particular to the iPhone, but I am looking for a solution that would work ideally cross-platform.

N.B. It seems that all solutions ultimately post to a REST-ful API on a remote server, as opposed to doing speech processing locally. (Is this true?)

Answer (score 9):

I can think of a few that are cross platform for Android and iOS. However, they are commercial services and at at some level of service you must pay for them. For Android, Google provides free speech recognition. So, you might want to consider using Google's free recognition for Android.

You can look at:

- The Nuance SDK - http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home
- iSpeech.org - https://www.ispeech.org/developers
- AT&T Watson - http://developer.att.com/developer/apiDetailPage.jsp?passedItemId=10700023
- Mozilla - https://wiki.mozilla.org/HTML5_Speech_API

If you want to try client side recognition on the mobile device. See:

- PocketSphinx - http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/
- OpenEars - http://www.politepix.com/openears/#

For some more background [Text-to-speech (voice generation) and speech-to-text (voice recognition) APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348770/text-to-speech-voice-generation-and-speech-to-text-voice-recognition-apis) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the mention of CMUSphinx software. The right link is actually http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net. This is the only offline speech recognition solution right now which can be used both on Androind and IPhone and Symbian.

Comment: @Michael Levy Can I find offline speech recognition for turkish on your examples? thanks in advance

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar, sorry. I do not know.

Comment: Perhaps @NikolayShmyrev would know?

Comment: I answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449086/how-can-i-do-voice-recognition-for-turkish-on-cmusphinx

Answer (score 0):

**Spitch**

https://www.spitch.ch/

Worth checking out, especially for German or Swiss German.

There are SDKs for iOS and Android.