# Local spoken command recognition on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, speech-recognition

I need to implement spoken command recognition in Android and iPhone apps without the use of internet communication - it all has to be processed locally on the devices and it must be able to distinguish 20-50 commands.

In other words: Local limited vocabulary speaker independent speech recognition running on both Android and iOS.

Using Google does not enlighten me enough so I was hoping for some advice from people having worked with this subject.

Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech to Text API or SDK for Mobile (Cross-Platform)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294762/speech-to-text-api-or-sdk-for-mobile-cross-platform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CMUSphinx.

CMUSphinx on IPhone through OpenEars:

http://www.politepix.com/

CMUSphinx on Android:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

Comment: But is this suited for speaker independent limited vocabulary use. Meaning not just speech to text but simple fast command recognition without any training or voice model adaptation?

Comment: Yes, that's what it supposed to do