# SFSpeechRecognizer that recognizes few command words instead of a whole phrase?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-to-text, sfspeechrecognizer

I have a SFSpeechRecognizer set up from Apple's sample app
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html

I was wondering if it was possible to have the recognizer recognize individual words that are not connected to other previously recognized words.

For example, the recognizer right now would try to form a sentence when "Scroll" is uttered and then find the best transcription for the word that makes sense so when "Stop" is uttered, it would change it to something like "Down" which makes more sense in the context of the previous word.

But this is not what I want as I want my app to listen to individual words as commands that call functions while listening.

Is there any way to implement the framework in such a way that it will continuously listen for words and only capture individual words uttered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local spoken command recognition on mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633270/local-spoken-command-recognition-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can scan the incoming words on partial results by setting `recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = YES` and then the results callback is called multiple times.

You can then process the results as you go, scanning for keyword / keyphrase before you get to the final result (ie ignore `result.isFinal`). When you find a keyword / keyphrase you are looking for, then just then cancel the recognition.

I have successfully implemented voice commands using this approach in [Speaking Email](http://www.speaking.email) as a modified Cordova plugin (source [here](https://github.com/mike-nelson/SpeechRecognitionPlugin)).

Example:

```
- (void) recordAndRecognizeWithLang:(NSString *) lang
{
        NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:lang];
        self.sfSpeechRecognizer = [[SFSpeechRecognizer alloc] initWithLocale:locale];
        if (!self.sfSpeechRecognizer) {
                [self sendErrorWithMessage:@"The language is not supported" andCode:7];
        } else {

                // Cancel the previous task if it's running.
                if ( self.recognitionTask ) {
                        [self.recognitionTask cancel];
                        self.recognitionTask = nil;
                }

                [self initAudioSession];

                self.recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
                self.recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = [[self.command argumentAtIndex:1] boolValue];

                self.recognitionTask = [self.sfSpeechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:self.recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult *result, NSError *error) {

                        if (error) {
                                NSLog(@"error");
                                [self stopAndRelease];
                                [self sendErrorWithMessage:error.localizedFailureReason andCode:error.code];
                        }

                        if (result) {
                                NSMutableArray * alternatives = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                int maxAlternatives = [[self.command argumentAtIndex:2] intValue];
                                for ( SFTranscription *transcription in result.transcriptions ) {
                                        if (alternatives.count < maxAlternatives) {
                                                float confMed = 0;
                                                for ( SFTranscriptionSegment *transcriptionSegment in transcription.segments ) {
                                                        NSLog(@"transcriptionSegment.confidence %f", transcriptionSegment.confidence);
                                                        confMed +=transcriptionSegment.confidence;
                                                }
                                                NSMutableDictionary * resultDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                                                [resultDict setValue:transcription.formattedString forKey:@"transcript"];
                                                [resultDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:result.isFinal] forKey:@"final"];
                                                [resultDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:confMed/transcription.segments.count]forKey:@"confidence"];
                                                [alternatives addObject:resultDict];
                                        }
                                }
                                [self sendResults:@[alternatives]];
                                if ( result.isFinal ) {
                                        [self stopAndRelease];
                                }
                        }
                }];

                AVAudioFormat *recordingFormat = [self.audioEngine.inputNode outputFormatForBus:0];

                [self.audioEngine.inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:recordingFormat block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {
                        [self.recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];
                }],

                [self.audioEngine prepare];
                [self.audioEngine startAndReturnError:nil];
        }
}
```

Comment: How I get the time stamp for each words so that I used it as Subtitle of Video ?? Please Suggest.