# How can I do voice recognition for Turkish on cmusphinx?

Tags: android, android-studio, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I imported this project:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo

And it works fine on Android studio.

But as you can see it on tutorial it has English voice recognition. How can I turn it to Turkish ? I searched a lot but I cant find it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to train the model yourself following the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

You have to collect transcribed speech data for that.

Alternatively you can contact people who already did that, for example [Sestek](http://www.sestek.com).

Answer (score 3):

You can check supported languages from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/)

If it is not implemented in the library itself, u cant add this feature by urself afaik. So u should find another library that already supports Turkish.

[image: supported languages]

Comment: In your link I can t see Turkish. So what you mean when saying this: So u should find another library that already supports Turkish. How can I find supported language?

Comment: Obviously Turkish is not listed above so it means this sdk doesnt support Turkish itself. you should do more effort to add a new language by training as Nikolay's answer says. If you think u can not add a new language so u look for another tts sdk. Maybe android's built-in tts support turkish i am not sure.