# Anyone familiar with the microsoft speech recognition API?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech

I'm writing some speech recognition code in python and I want it to be able to turn on the microsoft speech recognition system, but I want that system to ignore all the regular gui interface commands. So that if I say something that it recognizes, it will ignore it and let my program handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a python API called [pyspeech](http://code.google.com/p/pyspeech/) that is a wrapper around the Microsoft speech APIs. See [pyspeech (python) - Transcribe mp3 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611373/pyspeech-python-transcribe-mp3-files) for some answers that may be helpful.

Typically, with the Microsoft speech API when people see the "regular GUI interface commands" it means that they have instantiated a shared recognizer. You need to instantiate an inproc recognizer. You do this by instantiating a SpeechRecognitionEngine() in your application. See [SpeechRecognitionEngine Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). I suspect you are instantiating a shared recognizer - [SpeechRecognizer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

There is a very good article about Microsoft Speech that was published a few years ago at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx. It is probably the best introductory article I’ve found so far. It is a little out of date, but very helfpul. (The AppendResultKeyValue method was dropped after the beta.)

These two questions may have some other good information for you:

1. [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re)
2. [SAPI and Windows 7 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem/4217638#4217638)