# Audio file to text file python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I want to convert an audio(ex: ".mp3") file to text file. I have tried different approaches like `pyspeech` and `speech recognition`, But i didn't get any answer. Is there any other way to do this..? Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455069/how-to-input-and-process-audio-files-to-convert-to-text-via-pyspeech-or-dragonfl unfortunately without a valid answer.

Comment: @ρss, Thanks for mentioning but there is also no solid answer

Answer (score 6):

Did you try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/ ? That sounds like exactly what you want.

I also found the [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) project via this [blog](http://www.vikparuchuri.com/blog/simple-speech-recognition-in-python/). It has Python bindings too (as mentioned in the article).

The other item I found was Google's Speech to Text API. You might want to check that out too. Here's a decent tutorial on this subject:

- http://codeabitwiser.com/2014/09/python-google-speech-api/

Comment: SpeechRecognition looks like it will do what you want. Note that it uses external speech to text engines on the web, so you'll need internet access and a key for whatever service option you use.Textract (http://textract.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) provides a simple, uniform interface for text extraction and uses SpeechRecognition for handling audio files.

Answer (score 2):

```
import speech_recognition as sr
print(sr.__version__)
r = sr.Recognizer()

file_audio = sr.AudioFile('file_audio.wav')

with file_audio as source:
   audio_text = r.record(source)

print(type(audio_text))
print(r.recognize_google(audio_text))
```

Comment: Do you know if is there a workaround to other idioms (portuguese) using Sphinx?

Answer (score 0):

way 1: convet audio file to bytes (0,1) with https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub or by `f = open("test.mp3", "rb") first16bytes = f.read(16)`

way 2: audio to speech convertors.eg.-convert to english or other language with pip libraries like `SpeechRecognition pydub`. (but i think you don't asked for this)

way 3: convert mp3 to Json. If anyone did this, then please share.