# Output words using speech recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am now doing work regarding speech recognition in C# using windows7. I don't know what I am doing wrong. This code doesn't gives any errors but at the same time it doesn't even recognize anything nor responds... Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine RecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
RecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
RecognitionResult Result = RecognitionEngine.Recognize();
StringBuilder Output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in Result.Words)
{
    Output.Append(word.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your input device works correct.
2. Try to increase initial silence interval (e.g. `RecognitionEngine.Recognize(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))` )

PS: I would use asynchronous recognition if I were you

Comment: can you help me where to download MICROSOFT SPEECH SAPI 5.4?

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a grammar? If you're on Windows 7, you should specify and load the Dictation grammar. Something like:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
Grammar dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
```

See [SAPI and Windows 7 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem/4217638#4217638) for an example I've posted before.

Comment: i found this link.. is this helpfull ? 
http://blindcrawler.com/blog/blog1.php/2010/09/09/tutorial-using-32-bit-sapi-5-voices-in-64-bit-windows-7

Comment: why is that link related? Are you using 32 bit SAPI 5 on 64 bit Windows 7? This article is also about using text to speech (TTS) voices, not Speech Recognition.

Comment: can you please find me any SPEECH TO TEXT API ? 
i am struggling in finding it ..
can you provide me with any helpfull link

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You said you were using C# on Windows 7. You posted a sample with classes from System.Speech.Recognition. The documentation is all at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554855.aspx and good helpful information is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361625.aspx