# Is it possible to use speech recognition in a device which doesn't have google voice search installed?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I tried using RecognizerIntent to use speech recognition in my android app. But the target device doesn't have Google Voice search installed. Is there any other way I can use speech recognition in an Android device that doesn't have Google Voice installed.

Comment: `RecognizerIntent` is an intent like any other. You don't need Google to use it, just find another app that responds to this intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using others libraries, take a look to the next post [Can CMU Sphinx be set up to recognize ~200 words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073856/android-speech-to-text-speech-recognition). I think that maybe is you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably first should detect if the user has installed Voice Search on his smartphone. If it doesn't, then redirect it to Google Play to [download it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch).

Comment: The google play version of the voice search is not accessible from the target device.