# Does NDEV / Dragon Mobile SDK require Internet access?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am looking into a way to integrate limited-vocabulary speech recognition into my Android app (since Google Voice Search relies on Internet access which isn't always available to users).

I found a [Nuance page](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home) enticing programmers to download NDEV or the "Dragon Mobile SDK" but if it requires Internet access just like Google Voice Search, why should I be even interested in it?

Unfortunately, Nuance's page is not very informative and requires you to register (and sign a dragonian agreement...) before you get a chance to spend time to download & play with the kit only to discover that it's not what you're looking for...

Do you happen to know whether the **speech-recognition part** of NDEV or he "Dragon Mobile SDK" require Internet access?

Do you know of any off-the-shelf SDK for Android that *doesn't* require Internet access (i.e. some limited-vocabulary speech recognition can be done locally on the Android device)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073856/android-speech-to-text-speech-recognition

Comment: Yes, it does.  I do know that Nuance developed an android service in house to do on device speech (I know because I wrote the android wrapper), but it was a giant apk with all the data files.  One of their selling points is a small size sdk.  So I doubt its in use in ndev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, NDEV does require Internet access. Their SDK is just an API wrapper + the UI with the microphone button (and the code necessary to capture the audio properly).

If you need local speech recognition, have a look at [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/), it's a great project.

Answer (score 0):

On most phones (with hardware powerful enough) Google's own speech recognition can be set to work offline.
Simply go to Settings->Language and Input-> Voice Search -> Offline Speech Recognition
There you'll be able to download data for any language you need available offline.

Comment: as long as Google Services are installed in the device. Not all devices have Google Services.