# How to run CMUSphinxAndroid example for voice recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, speech-synthesis

I want to convert Audio file to text. So, I have found link 
[Can CMU Sphinx be set up to recognize ~200 words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073856/android-speech-to-text-speech-recognition)
to use CMUSphinx library to do this. Do this I followed the

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/
 and try to run android example. But I could not found sample project there.Is some one used to compile this code if yes than please tell me how to run in window specific OS.Is there any need to install cygwig and swig to compile build.

EDIT:
I have downloaded code from http://code.google.com/p/itce-team8-2012/source/browse/trunk/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo . Now when I compile and run code than application crashed.
Find log as below

```
04-15 17:58:12.584: D/dalvikvm(19618): Trying to load lib /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x41b9e1c0
04-15 17:58:12.584: D/dalvikvm(19618): Added shared lib /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x41b9e1c0
04-15 17:58:12.584: D/dalvikvm(19618): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x41b9e1c0, skipping init
04-15 17:58:12.649: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(19618): waiting
04-15 17:58:12.684: D/libEGL(19618): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-15 17:58:12.689: D/libEGL(19618): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-15 17:58:12.689: D/libEGL(19618): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-15 17:58:12.694: D/(19618): Device driver API match
04-15 17:58:12.694: D/(19618): Device driver API version: 10
04-15 17:58:12.694: D/(19618): User space API version: 10 
04-15 17:58:12.694: D/(19618): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
04-15 17:58:12.729: D/OpenGLRenderer(19618): Enabling debug mode 0
04-15 17:58:12.729: E/SensorManager(19618): thread start
04-15 17:58:12.729: D/SensorManager(19618): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41bc3538
04-15 17:58:14.374: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(19618): signalling START
04-15 17:58:14.374: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(19618): signalled START
04-15 17:58:14.374: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(19618): gotSTART
04-15 17:58:14.374: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(19618): START
04-15 17:58:14.499: A/libc(19618): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000001c (code=1), thread 19639 (Thread-3329)
```

Comment: Did you follow the first link on the updated tutorial? It contains a [very detailed howto](https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/home/pocketsphinxandroiddemo). Probably you should just be more attentive

Comment: @Nikolay yes that is given in detail but link is given for demo is not open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run demo successfully.My mistake is that i didn't change sd card path in config file.

Comment: Can you mention the name of config file?