# API from Windows 7 Speech recognition?

Tags: java, .net, windows-7, speech-recognition

Is there any api(for .net or java) from Windows 7 Speech recognition?

I would like to customize some aspects of this amazing feature from Windows 7

thanks

Comment: Something like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: sounds promising, do you know if there is something similar for java?

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but looks like this may work: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-guide/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech recognition in Windows can be programmed through the SAPI C++ api or the System.Speech .NET namespace.

There is a very good article that was published a few years ago at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx. It is probably the best introductory article I’ve found so far. It is a little out of date, but very helfpul. (The AppendResultKeyValue method was dropped after the beta.)

For more .NET info, see [SAPI and Windows 7 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem) and [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/)

Answer (score 0):

[CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) is  library written in C.It is a open source toolkit for speech recognition.

Sphinx4(wrapper) is a adjustable, modifiable recognizer written in Java