# Using c++ to call and use Windows Speech Recognition

Tags: c++, windows, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I am making an application that involves the use of windows speech recognition. I am thinking of using c++ to do this since i have some experience with this language. The way i want to use the speech recognition is so that it works internally. If i upload an audio file into my program, i want speech recognition to write this audio up as a text file, but all this should be done internally. Please provide some help with this and if i have not explained my question properly please let me know and i will try to explain again.

Thanks in advance,
Divs

Answer (score 5):

(Old question, but no accepted answer, and appears quite high in google)

If you really want to do this in C++, you have to download the SAPI SDK, which does not come standard with Windows : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5e86ec97-40a7-453f-b0ee-6583171b4530&displaylang=en , select SpeechSDK51.exe

The best documentation you can find on SAPI is not on the web, it's in the SDK itself, in the Docs/ folder. The .chm explains everything really well. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#InitializeCOM) is an additional link to get you started.

However, it C++ is not a requirement for you, I strongly recommend you do it in C#. It's really much simpler (no COM components, no separate SDK, more doc on MSDN, more tutorials, ...) . See [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/Vista_Speech_Recognition.aspx?msg=3047448); you'll have to remove all the GUI stuff, and all the speech synthesis stuff, and you'll see, speech recognition boild down to 10 lines of code. Quite impressive.

EDIT sample code, not compiled, not tested :

```
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

// in constructor or initialisation
SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = null;
recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

// The callback called when a sentence is recognized
private void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e){
    string text = e.Result.Text;
    // Do whatever you want with 'text' now
}
```

ta dah, done

Answer (score 3):

Windows provides speech recognition engines for both clients and servers. Both can be programmed with C++ or with .NET languages. The traditional API for programming in C++ is known as SAPI. The .NET framework namepsaces for client and server speech are System.Speech and Microsoft.Speech.

SAPI documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(VS.85).aspx

The .NET namespace for client recognition is System.Speech - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx. Windows Vista and 7 include the speech engine.

The .NET namespace for server recognition is Microsoft.Speech and the complete SDK for the 10.2 version is available at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b1604d3-4f66-4241-9a21-90a294a5c9a4. The speech engine is a free download.

Lots of earlier questions have addressed this. See [Prototype based on speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865351/prototype-based-on-speech-recognition/3867083) and [SAPI and Windows 7 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem/4217638) for examples.

Comment: And the article Elemental linked to (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx) is very helpful.