# Voice/Speech to text

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I need an API or library (preferably free) that will convert voice/speech through a microphone, into text (string).

Additionally, I will need an API or library that can do text-to-speech.

I'd like to use C# and .NET, but other languages will suffice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can use CMU Sphinx as it is pretty open and scalable solution and I think it can be used at both client and server side:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

If you are looking for a Microsoft desktop solution then you can use SAPI:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx

On server side, you can use Microsoft Unified Communication, but do consider licencing as well:

http://www.microsoft.com/uc/en/gb/default.aspx

Update:

This thread has also some good reference:

[C# Speech Recognition - Is this what the user said?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227140/c-speech-recognition-is-this-what-the-user-said)

Comment: Just updated answer with one more link.

Comment: You don't need UCS if you only need speech recognition on Windows Server. You can download the free Microsoft Speech Platform - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b1604d3-4f66-4241-9a21-90a294a5c9a4.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks for your post and it looks interesting.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a complete example using C# and System.Speech for converting from speech to text

The code can be divided into 2 main parts:

configuring the SpeechRecognitionEngine object (and its required elements)
handling the SpeechRecognized and SpeechHypothesized events.

**Step 1: Configuring the SpeechRecognitionEngine**

```
_speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
_speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
_dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
_speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(_dictationGrammar);
_speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

At this point your object is ready to start transcribing audio from the microphone. You need to handle some events though, in order to actually get access to the results.

**Step 2: Handling the SpeechRecognitionEngine Events**

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized -= new EventHandler(SpeechRecognized);
>   _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechHypothesized -= new EventHandler(SpeechHypothesizing);
>
> _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler(SpeechRecognized);
>   _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler(SpeechHypothesizing);
>
> private void SpeechHypothesizing(object sender,
>   SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e) { 
>   ///real-time results from the engine
>   string realTimeResults = e.Result.Text; }
>
> private void SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs
>   e) { 
>   ///final answer from the engine string finalAnswer =
>   e.Result.Text; }

That’s it. If you want to use a pre-recorded .wav file instead of a microphone, you would use

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile(pathToTargetWavFile);

instead of

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

There are a bunch of different options in these classes and they are worth exploring in more detail.

http://ellismis.com/2012/03/17/converting-or-transcribing-audio-to-text-using-c-and-net-system-speech/

Comment: can we use SpeechRecognitionEngine for android applications using MONO Framework???

Comment: Nope.  Need some Visual Studio for that.

Comment: @bulltorious Incorrect. Mono is a Linux emulator for .NET, so yes, this will work with Mono. *Also: Visual Studio is an IDE, not a programming language.*

Answer (score 2):

See [Using c++ to call and use Windows Speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609761/using-c-to-call-and-use-windows-speech-recognition/4616663#4616663)

Which says:

Microsoft provides speech recognition engines for both client and server versions of Windows. Both can be programmed with C++ or with .NET languages. The traditional API for programming in C++ is known as SAPI. The .NET framework namepsaces for client and server speech are System.Speech and Microsoft.Speech.

SAPI documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(VS.85).aspx

The .NET namespace for client recognition is System.Speech - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx. Windows Vista and 7 include the speech engine.

The .NET namespace for server recognition is Microsoft.Speech and the complete SDK for the 10.2 version is available at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b1604d3-4f66-4241-9a21-90a294a5c9a4. The speech engine is a free download.

Lots of earlier questions have addressed this. See [Prototype based on speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865351/prototype-based-on-speech-recognition/3867083) , [getting started with speech recognition and speech synthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881015/getting-started-with-speech-recognition-and-speech-synthesis) , and [SAPI and Windows 7 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem/4217638) for examples.

Answer (score -1):

`I'd like to use C# and .NET, but other languages will suffice.` Check this if you are open to `C++` [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/)

Answer (score -1):

There is a builtIn DLL in every Windows OS for Text2Speach. You will find the according dll in c:\Programs\Shared Folders\Microsoft Shared\Speech\sapi.dll (sAPI - speach api) - I am not quite sure about the path - but in anyway you may search for sapi.dll.

Afterwards you may use the following code snippet

```
SpVoice oVoice = new SpVoice();
oVoice.Voice = oVoice.GetVoices("","").Item(0); // 0 indicating what kind of speaker you want
oVoice.Volume = 50;
oVoice.Speak("hello world", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
oVoice = null;
```

Comment: This is the path for Win7 C:\Windows\System32\Speech\Common

Comment: Speech to Text... not the other way around.

Comment: @RobHay "Additionally, I will need an API or library that can do text-to-speech" so I think my answer is - at least - partially correct.

Answer (score -1):

For text to speech conversion you have to follow 3 steps:

1.Add System.Speech reference.

2.Add Headers:

using System.Speech;

using System.Speech.Synthesis;

3.Add the following code where textBox1 is a Text Box default name.

```
            SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            speaker.Rate = 1;
            speaker.Volume = 100;
            speaker.Speak(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Except it is going the opposite direction from the question; instead of speech-to-text, this shows text-to-speech.