# Save voice in text format

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, speech-to-text

In Windows Phone 7, how we can convert speech or voice data into text format. 
Please send me a link or explain it.

In my case, I want to convert speech data into text data and compare it with database values and perform some actions according to speech.

Answer (score 0):

thr is already a question is being asked about your issue..so here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677471/voice-speech-to-text)..hope it helps you..